# Генерация ссылок или qr-кодов для СБП

Tags: qrcode

Нужно автоматизировать банковские переводы между физ лицами. Хочется генерировать ссылку или qr-код для перевода по СБП, зная все данные получателя и сумму. Как это можно сделать физическому лицу?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно документации, регистрация QR кода или функциональной ссылки доступна для агентов ТСП (торгово-сервисных предприятий). Аналогичного функционала для физлиц не предусмотрено.

```
https://HOST/QR_ID?type=QR_TYPE&bank=MEMBER_ID&sum=SUM&cur=CUR&crc=CRC
```

Без регистрации в СПБ не получить QR_ID. Максимум, чего мне удалось добиться, это редирект в приложение банка на iOS при открытии ссылки, где указан его идентификатор.